# django rest framework autorization returns wrong status code

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, http-status-codes

I am new to django. I have a project that mobiles can have interaction with server using a token. In settings.py I have:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'UPLOADED_FILES_USE_URL': False,

    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': None,
    'PAGE_SIZE': DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE,  # For views using PageNumberPagination
}
```

but when using postman I send a request with an invalid token, istead of 401 (unauthorized), 403 (forbidden) is returning. Is there anything special I can do to fix this?

tnx

Comment: show the view atleast

Comment: seems to be csrf issue.. try adding csrf_exempt

Comment: the problem is I don't know how is that working. there is no view specified for this, or at least I couldn't find one. @Exprator

Comment: he is asking about your method to which you are hitting

Comment: he's asking to show your respective `views.py`

Answer (score 2):

As stated by the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#unauthorized-and-forbidden-responses):

> The kind of response that will be used depends on the authentication scheme. Although multiple authentication schemes may be in use, only one scheme may be used to determine the type of response. The first authentication class set on the view is used when determining the type of response.

Adds this extract from [SessionAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication)

> Unauthenticated responses that are denied permission will result in an HTTP 403 Forbidden response.

And you have your answer.

Either move `TokenAuthentication` as first `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` or document the current behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You still can define a custom exception handler that would send a `HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED` exception when `AuthenticationFailed` or `NotAuthenticated` exceptions occur.

[Official documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)

You can do it like so (from [this answer](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5968#issuecomment-578273212) on a GitHub issue):

```py
from rest_framework import exceptions
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler


def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    if isinstance(exc, (exceptions.AuthenticationFailed, exceptions.NotAuthenticated)):
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
    return response
```

and configure it in your `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings :

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # ...
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'path.to.your.custom_exception_handler',
    # ...
}
```